# Nested list comprehension with dependent conditional

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, list-comprehension, ternary-operator

I am trying to put this conditional clause into my list comp "arr".

```
arr = [[(i*n+j) for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
```

with

```
if ( 2*i<=j+i+1<=n+1 and i>0)
```

as the conditional. I tried putting this:

-with a else statement in a ternary at the front: "" , yet this produces unwanted elements in the array.

-as is after my for statements (i, j, and even tried both)

Any Ideas on how to get this to compute without adding to much complexity?

Desired Example Ouput:

```
from pandas import DataFrame as df
n = 5
arr= [NEEDS HELP HERE]

print(df(arr))

>>> 
   0   1    2     3    4
0 NaN  5   NaN   NaN  NaN
1 NaN  6  11.0   NaN  NaN
2 NaN  7  12.0  17.0  NaN
3 NaN  8  13.0   NaN  NaN
4 NaN  9   NaN   NaN  NaN
```

FOR n = 3

```
>>>  
   0   1    2 
0 NaN  3  NaN
1 NaN  4  7.0
2 NaN  5  NaN
```

For n = 2

```
>>> 
   0   1 
0 NaN  2
1 NaN  3
```

For n = 10 (my code can generate the below)

```
>>>
  0   1   2   3   4   5  6  7  8  9
0  _  10   _   _   _   _  _  _  _  _
1  _  11  21   _   _   _  _  _  _  _
2  _  12  22  32   _   _  _  _  _  _
3  _  13  23  33  43   _  _  _  _  _
4  _  14  24  34  44  54  _  _  _  _
5  _  15  25  35  45  55  _  _  _  _
6  _  16  26  36  46   _  _  _  _  _
7  _  17  27  37   _   _  _  _  _  _
8  _  18  28   _   _   _  _  _  _  _
9  _  19   _   _   _   _  _  _  _  _
```

As you can see each should produce a nxn matrix.
(I can replace each "_" with np.NaN)

I will post the solution below. Thanks So much for all the contributions.

Comment: While inserting that condition into your comprehension is straightforward, it seems like it would make more sense to adjust the bounds of the inner `range`.

Comment: I'm going to try to 'rotate' the list CW, and insert a empty list into index 0. If any other method please let me know. (will tell you if it works)

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in the inner list comprehension:

```
arr = [[(i*n+j) for i in range(n) if ( 2*i<=j+i+1<=n+1 and i>0)] for j in range(n)]
```

Output:

```
n = 10 # for example
print(arr)

[[10],
 [11, 21],
 [12, 22, 32],
 [13, 23, 33, 43],
 [14, 24, 34, 44, 54],
 [15, 25, 35, 45, 55],
 [16, 26, 36, 46],
 [17, 27, 37],
 [18, 28],
 [19]]
```

**EDIT:**

If you want it in a DataFrame with your desired output:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n = 10
arr = [[np.NaN] + [(i*n+j) for i in range(n) if ( 2*i<=j+i+1<=n+1 and i>0)] + [np.NaN] * (n - j - 2) for j in range(n)]

pd.DataFrame(arr)
```

---

```
    0   1     2     3     4     5   6   7   8   9
0 NaN  10   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1 NaN  11  21.0   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2 NaN  12  22.0  32.0   NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3 NaN  13  23.0  33.0  43.0   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4 NaN  14  24.0  34.0  44.0  54.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
5 NaN  15  25.0  35.0  45.0  55.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
6 NaN  16  26.0  36.0  46.0   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7 NaN  17  27.0  37.0   NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
8 NaN  18  28.0   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
9 NaN  19   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: Ok this gets me close to what I'm looking for. Im using Pandas DataFrame() to print out the actual array version of this. Yet, I need this to represent a square matrix where the first column is a 'filled' with NaN, the second (for n=10, is 10->19) and so on, where the last column may or may not be filled to fully produce a square matrix. I'm going to update my question with an desired output in a bit. Thanks so much for your contribute.

Comment: @Numoru Is there another issue?

Comment: It is close it doesn't work for all n cases >1. The matrix should maintain a nxn form.

Comment: @Numoru Can you add desired output for, say, `n = 8`, or `n = 9`, or `n = 10`? You won't be able to get a square regardless of whether you pad the last column or not.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer since I can use np.NaN in the code I already wrote I will post solution.

Comment: @Timothy32 see my solution

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify things a little as @user2357112 suggested:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n = 6
arr = ([i*n+j for i in range(1,n-j+1) if i<=j+1] for j in range(n))
df = pd.DataFrame([np.NaN]+x+[np.NaN]*(n-len(x)-1) for x in arr)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    0   1     2     3   4   5
0 NaN   6   NaN   NaN NaN NaN
1 NaN   7  13.0   NaN NaN NaN
2 NaN   8  14.0  20.0 NaN NaN
3 NaN   9  15.0  21.0 NaN NaN
4 NaN  10  16.0   NaN NaN NaN
5 NaN  11   NaN   NaN NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pandas import DataFrame as df
import numpy as np
n = {USERINPUT_Var_(int>1)}

arr = [[i*n+j if ( 2*i<=j+i+1<=n+1 and i>0) else np.NaN for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]

print(df(arr))
```

I could still use some help simplifing the conditional now.

Comment: Please avoid asking more questions unrelated to the original questions and wanting answers. Ask a new question if necessary.

Comment: @Tomothy32 Thanks for your help. Should I ask another question to see who can reduce the conditional, given this form? (Also sorry for misspell of name in other comment)

Comment: This is the correct final answer. Tomothy32's is a shortcut with inefficiencies being one can not apply zip() and other matrix methods due to it's incompleteness of 'filling' all necessary elements of the matrix with np.Nan.